# how to access react-spring variables inside a nested tag

Tags: reactjs, react-spring

I have the following code on which I would like to move the line `strokeDashoffset={spring.x.interpolate(x => strokeDasharray - x)}` inside the `<polygon ...` tag.

function Star(props) {

```
const strokeDasharray = 156
const spring = useSpring(
    {
        to: { x: strokeDasharray * (props.is/props.max), points: props.is },
    }
)

return(
    <animated.svg
    viewBox="0 0 45 45"
    style={{
        margin: "0px",
        width: "45px",
        height: "45px"
    }}
    strokeDashoffset={spring.x.interpolate(x => strokeDasharray - x)}
    >
        <polygon
        fill="#hite"
        stroke="red"
        strokeDasharray={strokeDasharray}
        points="22.5 35.25 8.68704657 42.5118994 11.3250859 27.1309497 0.150171867 16.2381006 15.5935233 13.9940503 22.5 0 29.4064767 13.9940503 44.8498281 16.2381006 33.6749141 27.1309497 36.3129534 42.5118994" />
    </animated.svg>
)
```

}

I want that, because I would like to add another path inside the svg with other values.

When I move it, the animation is gone and the path is fully filled immediately. But why?
How can I access the `spring.x` value inside the `polygon` instead of just inside the `animated.svg`?

Answer (score 0):

It is way easier than I thought:

Just use `<animated.polygon ... />` instead of `<animated.svg .../>`